# Running multiple Ruby on Rails web apps on a single Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, subdomain, azure, ruby-on-rails

I have 5 Ruby on Rails web apps and I want to run them from a single Azure Linux VM in order to save expenses. Actually I wanted to run them as Web Apps but Ruby on Rails is not yet supported.

I am able to run one of them and I assign the public port 80 to the private port 3000. Then I have assigned the subdomain `demo1.example.com` to `myapp.cloudapp.net` and works perfectly.

How should I proceed with the rest of them, so that they can be accessible from `demo2.example.com` and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Apache, create separate virtual host definitions for each "app".

For example:

```
<VirtualHost app1.arturo.com:80>
ServerName app1.arturo.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/app1.arturo.com/public
</VirtualHost>

[...]

<VirtualHost app5.arturo.com:80>
ServerName app5.arturo.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/app5.arturo.com/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How should I configure the endpoints on Azure? I already have the 3000-80 port-mapping. I was thinking on running the other apps on 3001, 3002... to port 80?

Comment: In addition, I am using Azure's default cloud service, which doesn't look to be Apache. Virtual directories are defined here: http://code-ninja.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/azure-virtual-directory-application.png